# Ideas to determine cutoff points for cancer classification?

Tags: classification

I am using a 36-gene signature to classify human samples into a specific category. In the signature, all genes are elevated. I have 997 human samples and would like to apply the gene signature. All genes are weighted equally. I was thinking of ranking the samples (by adding all the gene values together), so that I would get one value that could be easily analyzed. The problem is: how could I establish a cut-off point for classification (i.e. after a certain rank, the human sample is not classified as the type of interest)? I was wondering if someone could please suggest ideas? Bootstrap resampling? Percentile analysis? Machine Learning? Or any paper doing something similar...

Thank you very much for your time!